# Detecting The Number Of Invalid Input(Using parseInt)

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program that allows the user to input 5 different numbers; but instead of displaying the numbers, I want to show the user how many errors / invalid inputs he has done. The problem is: I don't exactly know how to do that, but so far I've managed to make a program but its not quite right.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TopicThirteen {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String msg = "";
        int num = 0;
        int counter;

        //for loop that gets the 5 numbers from the user
        for(counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++) {
            try {
                num = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                        "Enter number " + (counter + 1)));
            } catch(Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error " + e);
            }
        }
        //sets msg to the string equivalent of input
        switch(num) {
        case 1:
            msg = "one Invalid Inputs";
            break;
        case 2:
            msg = "two Invalid Inputs";
            break;
        case 3:
            msg = "three Invalid Inputs";
            break;
        case 4:
            msg = "four Invalid Inputs";
            break;
        case 5:
            msg = "five Invalid Inputs";
            break;
        }
        // displays the number in words if with in range
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ... good way to present the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need one more variable to keep the count and increment that counter on every wrong input i.e inside the catch block. To be more specific in terms of number parsing exception, you should use `NumberFormatException`:

```
int wrongInputCounts = 0 ;
//for loop that gets the 5 numbers from the user
for(counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++){

    try{

        num = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number "+(counter+1)));

    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        wrongInputCounts++;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,num + " is not a valid number");
    }
}
```

then switch on wrongInputCounts:

```
switch(wrongInputCounts){
```

Comment: Juned he is not doing anything with the num you might as well just remove it.

Comment: @wrongAnswer i have used it in showMessageDialog now ;-)

Comment: You could also avoid using the `switch` by using an array

Answer (score 1):

What about this version:

```
public class TopicThirteen
{   
    public static void main(String[] args){

        String msg = "";
        int num =0;
        int counter;

        //for loop that gets the 5 numbers from the user
        for(counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++){

            try{

                Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number "+(counter+1)));

            }catch(Exception e){
                num++;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error "+e);
            }
        }

        msg = num + " invalid input(s)";
        //displays the number in words if with in range
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,msg);
    }
}
```

As you said you don't have to catch the user input but the user input errors.